# String decrypted by vb.net function is different than the original String encrypted by java function

Tags: java, android, asp.net, vb.net, encryption

I have an Android app that uses a webservice in an asp.net web application. This web service requires a username and encrypted password.
The problem is that the password decrypted by the vb.net function is not the same that the original password encrypted by the java function.
These are the functions:

### java

```
public String encrypt(String password, String key, String VecI) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    byte[] sessionKey = key.getBytes(); 
    byte[] iv = VecI.getBytes() ; 
    byte[] plaintext = password.getBytes();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(sessionKey, "DES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
    String resp = ciphertext.toString();
    return resp;
}
```

### vb.net

```
Public Shared Function decrypt(Byval encrypted_password As String, ByVal key As String, ByVal VecI As String) As String
    Dim plaintext() As Byte= Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted_password)
    Dim keys() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)
    Dim memdata As New MemoryStream
    Dim transforma As ICryptoTransform
    Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider
    des.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    transforma = des.CreateEncryptor(keys, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VecI))
    Dim encstream As New CryptoStream(memdata, transforma, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    encstream.Write(plaintext, 0, plaintext.Length)
    encstream.FlushFinalBlock()
    encstream.Close()
    Return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memdata.ToArray)
End Function
```

Please, help me.

Thank`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side you're expecting a Base64 encoded string, which you're then converting to a byte array:

```
Dim plaintext() As Byte= Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted_password)
```

You should be doing the opposite of this on Android (converting the byte array to a Base64 string). Instead you're just calling `toString` on a `byte[]`, which definitely won't give you what you want.

You can get the Base64 encoded string from your byte array as follows:

```
String resp = Base64.encode(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

You can have a look at the [Base64 docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) for more information. You may have to play around with the flags supplied.

Another thing to consider is the fact that you're expecting everything to be in ASCII encoding. `String.getBytes()` returns characters encoded [using the systems default charset](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29). Passwords may be input using non-ASCII characters, such as é or ¥, and this could introduce subtle bugs. I'd recommend switching everything over to UTF-8 - server-side and client side (that means changing `getBytes()` to `getBytes("UTF-8")`, and `Encoding.ASCII` to `Encoding.UTF8`).

As an aside, creating a String from a byte array in Java is done using `new String(someByteArray, "UTF-8")` - or whatever the encoding you're using is.